# Creating new exception in C++

Tags: c++, linux, exception, ubuntu

I have a C++ class and I am trying to run it in Ubuntu:

```
#ifndef WRONGPARAMETEREXCEPTION_H_
#define WRONGPARAMETEREXCEPTION_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma once

class WrongParameterException: public exception
{
    public:
        WrongParameterException(char* message): exception(message) {};
        virtual ~WrongParameterException() throw() {};
}; 

#endif
```

when I try to compile it, the compiler gives me this error:

```
WrongParameterException.h: In constructor ‘WrongParameterException::WrongParameterException(char*)’:
WrongParameterException.h:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::exception::exception(char*&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/exception:59: note: candidates are: std::exception::exception()
/usr/include/c++/4.3/exception:57: note: std::exception::exception(const std::exception&)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I tried changing the message variable to `string` or `const string` or `const string&` but it didn't help.

Here is how I use the new exception that I created from main:

```
try
{
     if ((strToInt1 == -1) || (parameters[1] == NULL) || (strToInt3 == -1) || (parameters[3] != NULL))
     {
          throw WrongParameterException("Error in the config or commands file");
     }
}
catch(WrongParameterException e)
{
     log.addMsg(e.what());
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but important: do not `use namespace std;` in a header. Second, learn about the standard exception classes C++ provides (std::runtime_error, logic_error, and domain_error etc.).  Catch by const&.  And don't include <iostream> for an exception header.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, `#pragma once` is the wrong way to go about it, learn about header include guards. [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/13986) explains why using `#pragma once` is the wrong way to go about it. Wikipedia explains how to use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which serve the same purpose without any of the downsides.

Second, you are calling the constructor of std::exception with a parameter it does not know, in this case a pointer to a character array.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class WrongParameterException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    WrongParameterException(const std::string& message) 
        : std::runtime_error(message) { };
};
```

Would probably be what you want. For more information on exceptions, check out [C++ FAQ Lite article on Exceptions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html) and the [exceptions article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions.html) at cplusplus.com.

Good luck!

Comment: Header guards are more correct and portable, but if you know the code is to be compiled with the MS compilers, then #pragma once will get you faster compilation (it doesn't have the parse the file again to find the matching #endif).

Comment: He specified that he is running this on Ubuntu, so I am assuming that is GCC. In which case the PRAGMA statement does not work in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure #pragma once is supported by the gcc version that was current when this comment was written. If not, its supported now - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/cpp/Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef.html

Comment: Even if GCC supports it, that does not mean alternate compilers support it. Not using `#pragma once` is a good idea.

Comment: `#pragma once` is [pretty widely supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).  Also, my ancient corporate environment uses GCC 3.4.2 and `#pragma once` is supported per my testing.

Comment: #pragma once works on MSVC, gcc and clang, use it! Duplicated macros for the manual way can cause a build nightmare

Comment: The Header Guard site you linked, http://graphics.cs.niu.edu/people/duffin/csci241/c241man/node90.html is down.

Comment: @luckydonald You are correct, and it seems that the wayback machine didn't keep a copy either :-(

Comment: @luckydonald: Here's a SO that specifies why not to use pragma once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/13986

Answer (score 9):

std::exception does not have a constructor that takes any kind of string, only a virtual what() method that returns the exception description.

You will have to store the string yourself and return it from there.

Answer (score 8):

My advice would be:

1. Inherit from `std::runtime_error`. As advised by X-Istence above. It is conceptually a runtime error, and also the `std::runtime_error` constructor accepts a `std::string` as argument describing what happened.
2. About your catching the exception. I'd use `catch(WrongParameterException const& e)`
    (note the const reference) instead of `catch(WrongParameterException e)`, because first, the exception is normally constant in your case, and, also, using the reference, you catch any subclass of `WrongParameterException` in case your code evolves with some more refined exception handling.

Answer (score 5):

std::exception's constructor doesn't take a string argument. You're trying to give it one, which is what causes the compile error.

You need to store your string, which would be better to handle as a std::string rather than a raw pointer, and return it from the `what()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the declaration of the exception class in MS VS2K5, the constructor you want is:

```
exception (const char *const&);
```

so try changing your constructor to:

```
WrongParameterException (const char *const message)
```

and see if that helps. Otherwise, store the pointer in your own class and implement all the relevant methods.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to design your exception diferently. Here is a simple example:

```
class MyException : public Exception
{
public:
   MyException(CString strError) { m_strError = strError; }

   CString m_strError;
};
```

Then you can simply use your exception message as you please. This is because Exception does not have a contructor that excepts a String, so you have to stlre it on your own.